# What is the UTF-8 code for Android Voice mail icon/symbol?

Tags: android, utf-8

I want to build the dialer and it got that strange voice mail icon under the latter 1. It seems like a text but I can't find it's code, I guess it's some special UTF-8 encoding.

What it's code?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Quickest sollution I could find was just adding it as an icon. I would also prefer the utf-8 code but couldn't find it.

Comment: You’re reviving a question that is two years old...?

Comment: @Terry I'm pretty sure I'm not going to be the last person looking for a sollution to this